# Create and store an object of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class named `Employee` and another (`reg_employee`) that instantiates the former class.

I want to know if this code can be improved.

```py
class Employee:

    def __init__(self):
        self.Name = ''
        self.Id = 0
        self.Age = 0
        self.company = 0
        self.title = ''
        self.Level = 0
        self.xp = 0.0
        self.Tasks = []
        self.Projects = []

    def setname(self, name):
        self.Name = name

    def setage(self, age):
        self.Age = age

    def setcompany(self, company):
        self.company = company

    def setxp(self, lvlup):
        self.xp = lvlup
```

```py
import Employee

class reg_employee:

    def __init__(self):
        self.employees = []

    def read_info(self, name, age, company):
        e = Employee.Employee()
        e.Name = name
        e.Age = age
        e.company = company
        self.employees.append(e)
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine. However, there are a few things you can do to improve it:

- first, avoid using Capital letters for variable. In Python, they should be named in [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case);
- use snake_case for `setters` (e.g., `set_name`) and `getters` as well, or use properties instead. See https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php for more information.
- You can avoid instantiating the variable in the `__init__`.
- If you are using Python 3.X, consider specifying the parameters types and return types.

Here is how I would refactor your code:

```py
class Employee:

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name: str):
        self.__name = name

    @property
    def age(self):
        return self.__age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, age: int):
        self.__age = age

    @property
    def company(self):
        return self.__company

    @company.setter
    def company(self, company: str):
        self.__company = company

    @property
    def xp(self):
        return self.__xp

    @xp.setter
    def xp(self, lvlup: float):
        self.__xp = lvlup
```

However, you should use setters if you need to perform some checks before assigning the value to the variable (e.g., you want to check that the passed `age  > 18` or that the title is at least "a bachelor degree", and so forth.
If you do not need those checks, you can simply call the variable, for example:

```py
class Employee:

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''
        self.id = 0
        self.age = 0
        self.company = 0
        self.title = ''
        self.level = 0
        self.xp = 0.0
        self.tasks = []
        self.projects = []


employee = Empolyee()
employee.name = 'Foo Bar'
employee.age = 30
```

Instead of using setters or populating the variables one by one, you can further improve the code by passing the parameters to the Employee class constructor:

```py
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, name:str, age:int, company:int, id:int=None, title:str=None,
                 xp=float=None, task:list=None, projects:list=None):
         
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.age = age
        self.company = company
        self.title = title
        self.level = level
        self.xp = xp
        self.tasks = tasks
        self.projects = projects

   # Properties here (getters and setters) ...
```

Then, `read_info` will become:

```py
def read_info(self, name, age, company):
    e = Employee.Employee(name=name, age=age, company=company)
    self.employees.append(e)
```

**Update**

As highlighted by [hjpotter](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/12240/hjpotter92), a more suitable approach in this case would use [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html).
Therefore, the class can be rewritten as:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Employee:

    name: str
    age: int
    company: int
    id: int = 0
    title: str = None
    level: int = 0
    xp: float = 0.0
    tasks: list = None
    projects: list = None
```

The `__init__` is created automatically, and a new object can be instantiated as in the previous example:

```py
def read_info(self, name, age, company):
    e = Employee.Employee(name=name, age=age, company=company)
    self.employees.append(e)
```

Comment: I usually tend to use `**kwargs` when I have to deal with a big number of arguments in a class which seems to be the case here as well.

Comment: in this specific case i think `dataclasses` are more suitable